# Face Recognition To Numbers

Tags: face-recognition

Okay I have been working on developing apps for ios and just kind of randomly following tutorials here and there hoping to learn more.

Recently I can across a online tutorial that walks you through using the face recognition

In this tutorial he has it where it takes one image and puts green dots around the persons eyes and a blue dot over there mouth.

my question is how can I change this so instead of putting a green and blue dot over them it would just return data like how far apart are there eyes and distance from eyes to mouth.

How would you do this here is the online tutorial that I was following.
http://maniacdev.com/2011/11/tutorial-easy-face-detection-with-core-image-in-ios-5/

Thank You

Comment: Interesting.. i think you need to first look into how or where the co-ordinates or the vertices are stored that are represented by those dots.

Comment: Ofcourse the question title would have to be edited as it is very unclear what you are trying to achieve..